# brute force python "out of range error"

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have a simple brute force program but cannot get it to work. The code generates a `string index out of range` error yet I find the string to be consistent with the range.

I typed aa as the password

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase[:]
#Get the password
passd = str.lower(input("Please enter you password: "))
rpass = []
counter = 0
i = 0
j = 0
while counter <= len(passd): 
   #Check if the letters match
   if alphabet[i] == passd[j]: 
    rpass.append(passd[j])
    i += 1
    j += 1
    counter += 1
  else:
    i += 1

print(rpass)
```

Comment: Please tell us _exactly_ what you typed at the prompt, and _exactly_ what error message you got.  Also please tell us whether this is Python 2 or 3.

Comment: (You can edit your question - see the tiny gray word "edit" under the "python" tag? That's a button.  Yes, really.)

Comment: @zwol Presumably this is Python 3, because of the `print` statement in the last line.

Comment: yap. It is python 3

Comment: @CaveinMuthama is your problem solved if you change `while counter <= len(passd)` to `while counter < len(passd)`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's important in Python and we cannot tell you what's wrong with your code if it's not properly indented.

Comment: Is that `else` suppose to be *inside* the while-loop?

Comment: @numbermaniac there is still an error

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga. No. else is part of if - else

Comment: @FJSevilla I have noticed that but what numbermaniac stated but after the changes the program is not working. The same error

Comment: @numbermaniac FYI, that works in Python 2.7 also.  Without a `__future__` import, even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` needs to be set to 0 to start again at the beginning of the alphabet when you've found a match, and your `while` should only check if `counter` is  `< len(passd)`:

```
while counter < len(passd): 
   #Check if the letters match
   if alphabet[i] == passd[j]: 
    rpass.append(passd[j])
    i = 0
    j += 1
    counter += 1
   else:
    i += 1
```

(Note that this does still seem to fail if you have a letter not part of the alphabet, such as a spacebar.)

As a side note, your input can be simplified to:

```
passd = input("Please enter your password: ").lower()
```